# trying to convert images to webp with imagemin-webp but not working

Tags: javascript, imagemin-webp

I found a code in a website for converting png, jpg to webp but it doesnt work for me. I have two jpg files in /images/ folder

```
const imagemin = require("imagemin"),
  webp = require("imagemin-webp");
const outputFolder = "./images/webp";
const produceWebP = async () => {
  await imagemin(["images/*.png"], {
    destination: outputFolder,
    plugins: [
      webp({
        lossless: true,
      }),
    ],
  });
  console.log("PNGs processed");
  await imagemin(["images/*.{jpg,jpeg}"], {
    destination: outputFolder,
    plugins: [
      webp({
        quality: 65,
      }),
    ],
  });
  console.log("JPGs and JPEGs processed");
};
produceWebP();
```

When i run node index.js i take the message you see in the photo

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is in `Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module`.

There are two types of modules in NodeJS: [CommonJS](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) and [ECMAScript modules (ESM)](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html).

CommonJS uses `const webp = require("imagemin-webp")` syntax.

While ESM uses `import webp from "imagemin-webp"` syntax to achieve the same result.

Your `index.js` is CommonJS and the [imagemin npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemin) is ESM and the error ocures when you try to use `require()` call to import ESM module.

There are two possible solutions for this:

- convert your `index.js` from CommonJS to ESM (preferred)
- use asynchronous `import()` call instead of `require()` to import ESM module from CommonJS

**First (and preferred) option** is to convert your code to ESM:

- rename `index.js` to `index.mjs` (`.mjs` extension indicates ESM syntax)
- change all `require()` calls to `import something from 'library'` calls
- run it as `node index.mjs`

`index.mjs`:

```
// using ES import syntax here
import imagemin from "imagemin";
import webp from "imagemin-webp";
// the rest of the file is unchanged
const outputFolder = "./images/webp";
const produceWebP = async () => {
    await imagemin(["images/*.png"], {
        destination: outputFolder,
        plugins: [
            webp({
                lossless: true,
            }),
        ],
    });
    console.log("PNGs processed");
    await imagemin(["images/*.{jpg,jpeg}"], {
        destination: outputFolder,
        plugins: [
            webp({
                quality: 65,
            }),
        ],
    });
    console.log("JPGs and JPEGs processed");
};
produceWebP();
```

**Second option** is to use asynchronous `import()` call to import ESM modules from CommonJS module as indicated in NodeJS [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_import_expressions).

It is not preferred because `import()` is asynchronous, I'd like to use `await` to get the result like `await import()` but this in-turn requires to be called inside another `async` function.

`index.js`:

```
const outputFolder = "./images/webp";
const produceWebP = async () => {
    // Load ESM modules using import(),
    // it returns a Promise which resolves to
    // default export as 'default' and other named exports.
    // In this case we need default export.
    const imagemin = (await import("imagemin")).default;
    const webp = (await import("imagemin-webp")).default;
    await imagemin(["images/*.png"], {
        destination: outputFolder,
        plugins: [
            webp({
                lossless: true,
            }),
        ],
    });
    console.log("PNGs processed");
    await imagemin(["images/*.{jpg,jpeg}"], {
        destination: outputFolder,
        plugins: [
            webp({
                quality: 65,
            }),
        ],
    });
    console.log("JPGs and JPEGs processed");
};
produceWebP();
```

*P.S.*
Please note that ESM can export more than one entry (default and named exports) while CommonJS can only export one entry.

Comment: Couldn't be a better explanation! Thank you very much!

Comment: I went with option 2... worked like a champ!